# How to use JWT with cakephp 2.10?

Tags: php, cakephp, jwt

I'm using CakePHP 2.10.9 version and trying to use token-based authentication instead of session-based authentication.

I couldn't find any information on how to use JWT with CakePHP 2.x.

Here is what I have tried so far.  As a first step, I downloaded the plugin t73biz/cakephp2-jwt-auth and added this into the folder `app/Plugin/JwtAuth`.  As mentioned in the usage(https://github.com/t73biz/cakephp2-jwt-auth), I added below configuration in the app/Controller/AppController.php

```
var $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'JwtAuth.JwtToken' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password',
                        'token' => 'public_key',
                    ),
                    'parameter' => '_token',
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'scope' => array('User.active' => 1),
                    'pepper' => 'sneezing',
                ),
            ),
        ),'Session','RequestHandler','Email','Flash');
```

From my past experience with Plugin's, I knew I'm supposed to include the plugin in bootstrap.php.

```
CakePlugin::load('JwtAuth');
```

I don't know what am I supposed to do after this. Could someone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't read the the [Authentication](https://github.com/t73biz/cakephp2-jwt-auth#authentication) part

> => The query string parameter defined as parameter in the config array (defaults to `_token`)
>
> =>The contents of the header defined as header in the config array (defaults to `X_JSON_WEB_TOKEN`)

It means when you access any method then you have to pass the `JWT` toekn with `query` params or Header request.

Sample Query params:
`http://example.com/users/add?_token=THEJWTWEVTOKEN`